# Autobahn: Display live stream from push api into webpage

Tags: node.js, api, websocket, live-streaming, autobahn

I am new to the concept of autobahn and I want to learn how to push the live stream of data from the push api into webpage.

The code below gives the live stream of output in the console. I want to display it on the webpage.

```
var autobahn = require('autobahn');
var wsuri = "wss://api.poloniex.com";
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
  url: wsuri,
  realm: "realm1"
});

connection.onopen = function (session) {
        function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        session.subscribe('BTC_XMR', marketEvent);

        function tickerEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function trollboxEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }

        session.subscribe('ticker', tickerEvent);
        session.subscribe('trollbox', trollboxEvent);
}

connection.onclose = function () {
  console.log("Websocket connection closed");
}

connection.open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe node.js is not the easiest solution here. You can download the autobahn.min.js from the git repository following the GitHub link for Autobahn|JS http://crossbar.io/autobahn/.
Just put the file in your websites directory and use it like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>   
<head>
 <script src="autobahn.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
                           url: 'wss://api.poloniex.com',
                           realm: 'realm1'
                        });

connection.onopen = function (session) {
        function marketEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        function tickerEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=args;
        }
        function trollboxEvent (args,kwargs) {
                console.log(args);
        }
        session.subscribe('BTC_XMR', marketEvent);
        session.subscribe('ticker', tickerEvent);
        session.subscribe('trollbox', trollboxEvent);
}
connection.onclose = function () {
  console.log("Websocket connection closed");
}               
connection.open();
</script>
</html>
```